# Promoting a Poker Website

Tags: halal-haram, profession

I have been given an offer to work for a poker website. This will involve writing articles about tournaments, about the sport, etc. Would these earnings be halal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bismillah.

This is a very interesting, and important subject. I will give you my honest opinion, and what I have been told concerning implementing oneself into activities that are considered haram.

Firstly, we obviously know that gambling is a sin, and some may argue that it is a major sin. Therefore, playing the game, and earning money from the game is a sin. That being said, associating yourself in any shape or form with the game is also, in my opinion, a sin. Whether your physically participating in the game or not is not an issue, but the fact that you would be in essence promoting the game, is a sin.

Let me give you a clear example. Many scholars argue that hotels, especially in the Muslim world, should not offer alcohol, because that is considered a sin. While the owner of the hotel may not actually touch or drink the alcohol, they still are promoting it by having it being sold in their hotel. Therefore, doing so would be a sin.

Please inform me if I'm been mistaken. Allah knows my intention and only He can forgive me for any fault doings of my own, inshAllah.